# Apple Reminders make no sound

Tags: reminders

I make use of Apple Reminders on my iOS 10 iPhone SE but there never is any sound when the reminder is due. Do not disturb mode is turned off but it doesn't seem to matter. Anyone else who has had this issue?

Comment: You’ve tried going into **Settings** → **Notifications** → **Reminders** → **Sounds** and selecting a different tone? Your ringer is not muted?

Answer (score 6):

This same issue drove me mad, not to mention almost making me miss an appointment, until I found the answer by accident. There are ***two*** places where the option to set the sound for a reminder appears (no, me neither).  The obvious one is:

***Settings>Notifications>Reminders (allow notifications)>Sounds***

Unfortunately, this is the wrong one.  The right one is in:

***Settings>Sounds>Reminder Alerts***

The phone will always follow the setting in Sounds, not the one in Notifications.  The same applies to calendar alerts.  Sigh.

Comment: I don't know if this was actually true in the past, but it certainly isn't in 2022. Those two paths are just two ways to get to the same place. It's not possible to have different settings in each; changing it from one changes the other - because they're the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I think the problem is that you have set "alert tones" in Reminder Alerts of settings. Use "ringtones" instead.

Comment: I doubt that's the problem. Alert tones are shorter sounds than ringtones, so it's true that they're easier to miss. But choosing an alert tone will not be the cause of not getting any sound at all, and changing from an alert tone to a ringtone will not be the solution to that problem.